# c# - How to store data in a FILE so the garbage collector don't delete them

Tags: c#, file, game-development

I'm in a early stage of making my game and I'm facing a problem... the garbage collector. I have a factory that create all the pokemons information, for exemple, here is magikarp :

```
        private PokemonInfo Magikarp()
        {
            //General Information
            int pokedex = 052;
            string name = "Magikarp";
            string description = "It is said to be the world’s weakest Pokémon. No one knows why it has managed to survive.";
            int gender = (int)Enum.gender.Both;
            double height = 0.9;
            double weight = 10;

            //Typing
            int type = (int)Enum.type.Water;

            //Abilities
            List<Ability> abilitiesPokemon = new List<Ability>();
            abilitiesPokemon.Add(abilities[(int)Enum.ability.Swift_Swim]);

            //Stats
            int baseHP = 20;
            int baseAttack = 10;
            int baseDefense = 55;
            int baseSpecialAttack = 15;
            int baseSpecialDefense = 20;
            int baseSpeed = 80;

            //Battle
            int catchrate = 255;
            int experience = (int)Enum.experience.Slow;
            int experienceYield = 20;

            //Moves
            List<Learnset> learnset = new List<Learnset>();
            List<Move> tmPokemon = new List<Move>();
            //========================================================Leveling
            learnset.Add(new Learnset(moves[(int)Enum.move.Splash], 1));
            learnset.Add(new Learnset(moves[(int)Enum.move.Tackle], 15));
            learnset.Add(new Learnset(moves[(int)Enum.move.Flail], 30));
            //========================================================TM
            tmPokemon.Add(moves[(int)Enum.move.Bounce]);

            return new PokemonInfo(pokedex, name, description, gender, height, weight, type, abilitiesPokemon, catchrate, experience, experienceYield, baseHP, baseAttack, baseDefense, baseSpecialAttack, baseSpecialDefense, baseSpeed, learnset, tmPokemon, Gyarados(), 20);
        }
```

Is there a way I can create a file with all my PokemonInfo data ? Something I can use like :

```
Pokedex.GetInfo(FILE.Magikarp).description;
```

I traveled across the web, searching far and wide, but I couldn't find the solution >.<

Comment: Protobuf? Or a database

Comment: This is an XY problem. That's not to say you shouldn't persist data to a file -- go ahead and do that -- but if the garbage collector is really collecting your objects, solve that first. *Metaphorically, you're leaving the moving van on the street with no one to watch it, so things are being stolen.* In other words, if you're not keeping at least one reference to each object you're creating, the garabage collector is free to collect them. As long as there's a reference to an object somewhere, the garbage collector will leave it alone.

Comment: Just to add slightly to @madreflection's comment, if the garbage collector is collecting these objects, you couldn't use them because you wouldn't have access to them anyway, so the GC isn't your problem.

Comment: @madreflection so, if there is a reference somewhere, my pokemon info will never gets ate by the garbage collector ? :3

Comment: Yes, *somewhere* that's accessible to user code. If the only reference to instance X is in a field in some other object instance Y that is not accessible to user code, then neither is instance X because the chain of access from user code is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class (or a static class) and declare static public properties (or fields) to hold your Pokemons.
In the static constructor, you can define (and store) all your Pokemons.

```cs
public class Pokemons
{
    static Pokemons()
    {
        // here you set variables for your Pokemon
        // Then you set the Pokemon to the static field
        Magikarp = new PokemonInfo(...);
    }

    public static readonly PokemonInfo Magikarp;
}
```

Somewhere in your code, you can access your Pokemons like that:

```cs
var myPokemon = Pokemons.Magikarp;
```

Comment: So, if my Pokedex class is a static one, containing a private static factory and a private static method to get the info, everything will be fine :3 ?

Comment: As long as you don't reassign the static properties or fields, garbage collector won't remove them.